# CentOS 6.3 compilation and ksig

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, rhel

While compiling CentOS 6.3 kernel, make fails with:

```
  CC      crypto/signature/dsa.o
crypto/signature/ksign-publickey.c:2:17: error: key.h: No such file or directory
crypto/signature/ksign-publickey.c: In function גksign_initג:
crypto/signature/ksign-publickey.c:10: error: גksign_def_public_keyג undeclared (first use in this function)
crypto/signature/ksign-publickey.c:10: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
crypto/signature/ksign-publickey.c:10: error: for each function it appears in.)
crypto/signature/ksign-publickey.c:11: error: גksign_def_public_key_sizeג undeclared (first use in this function)
make[2]: *** [crypto/signature/ksign-publickey.o] Error 1
```

According to [this](http://jira.whamcloud.com/browse/LU-624) it's related to [Linux module signing](http://lwn.net/Articles/222162/) (a.k.a `KSIG`), which was dropped by Linux in RHEL 6.1.

I'm trying to see if the [proposed solution](http://lwn.net/Articles/222162/) is indeed correct or 
there's another solution to the problem.

Reference that RHEL abandoned `KSIG` will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error too, but it is in CentOS 6.4, both x86_64 and i386 version.

Run:

```
`make menuconfig`
```

and:

- Select `Enable loadable module support`, then `Module signature verification (EXPERIMENTAL)`. Disable it.
- Then go back to the main menu, select `Cryptographic API` then `In-kernel signature checker (EXPERIMENTAL)` and disable that one too.

Comment: The above link is no longer available, just keep it for attribution and historical reason.   But there are others:
http://www.cnblogs.com/qatest/archive/2013/02/25/CentO_Compile_error.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why not exist key.h in crypto/signature! 
for ignoring error you must not select: "in-kernel signature checker" in "cryptographic API" and "Module signature verification" in "Enable loadable module support".
I think that centos script not run correctly in ubuntu.